# Pass arguments to a command prompt using c#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am trying disable or enable users at local computer as shown in the code below. I am creating a exe and prompting users to enter username which they want to enable or disable.

Now I want to pass the arguments to a command prompt and disable or enable users. For eg:>cmd.exe John Disable.

How to pass arguments to a command prompt using c# and use the same code below to enable or disable users?

```
class EnableDisableUsers
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter user account to be enabled or disabled");
                string user = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter E to enable or D to disable the user account");
                string enableStr = Console.ReadLine();
                bool enable;

            if (enableStr.Equals("E") || enableStr.Equals("e"))
            {


                PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);

                // find a user
                UserPrincipal username = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, user);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Enable User
                        username.Enabled = true;
                        username.Save();
                        Console.WriteLine(user + " Enabled");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Operation failed - Username is not valid", e.Message);
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (enableStr.Equals("D") || enableStr.Equals("d"))
            {


                PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);

                // find a user
                UserPrincipal username = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, user);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Disable User
                        username.Enabled = false;
                        username.Save();
                        Console.WriteLine(user + " Disabled");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Operation failed - Username is not valid", e.Message);
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you mean "how do I *read* the arguments passed to my program?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Command Prompt Commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Comment: If any one of the 6 answers provided have resolved your issue, please mark the answer as correct with the check mark. Use the up arrows to show that a post is helpful, even if it does not solve your issue. Doing so will ensure continued help in the future for any questions you may have :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.Arguments = "/c ping " + machine;
processStartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
process.Start();
```

Here's an example using the ping command in console.  You can add other options like forcing it to not open the gui etc.

Comment: his project is a console app. so he doesn't need a new cmd window.

Answer (score 0):

You may use  `Environment.CommandLine` to read command line argument or  [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs) methods.

```
 String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at the

```
string[] args
```

Your command-line arguments are inside the string array.

Answer (score 0):

the arguments sent to your program are stored in `args`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 switch (args[x])
 {
      .... 

  }
```

for example

```
 switch (args[x])
 {
  #region --loop
  case "--loop":               
      x = -1;
      break;
 #endregion

 #region --test-net
     case "--test-net":
          Task isAlive = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
          {
              bool alive = tlib.CheckForInternetConnection();
              if (!alive)
              {
                  while (!alive)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("No connectivity found.");
                      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(9000);
                      alive = tlib.CheckForInternetConnection();
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                   //TODO: Add alive code here 
              }
          });
          isAlive.Wait();
          break;

          #endregion
}
```

This allows you to say prog.exe --test-net and run that specific code.

--edit--

With multiple args you can string together a command, in this instance

```
prog.exe --test-net --loop
```

You can have as many args as you want. If you want to use human input for an arg you can always control the amount of args and grab args[x+1] to get the name of the person to disable/enable.

This is making an assumption that your case statements have 2 cases: --enable and --disable for instance. Then you can call the program like:

```
prog.exe --enable John
```

Comment: Can I pass multiple args[] inside switch ?

Comment: absolutely, just separate each arg with a new case statement. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in your Main? If so, you would refer to the command line arguments from the string[] args:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

You can see some examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457(v=vs.71).aspx